# Get json from misformatted json string

Tags: java, json

I have a json string, which look like that:

```
data: { "type": "add",
"newsId": "5da979e0-161d-11e7-9e14-bd201bbe920c",
"articleId": "null",
"category": "news",
"timestamp": "1490970103941",
"id": "5daa8b50-161d-11e7-9e14-bd201bbe920c"}
```

I've created pojo to parse this json using Gson.

```
public class SSENewsEvent {

    private String type;

    private String newsId;

    private String articleId;

    private String category;

    private String timestamp;

    private String id;
}
```

But, as you can see, it cannot be parsed because it's somehow misformatted by this

```
data:
```

at the beginning of the string. Can you help me to find the best way to parse this string?

Comment: The json string should start with `{` How about checking if the first character is `{` in the string else add a `{` at the start and `}` at the end? Will this work for you?

Comment: I've added this curly brackets at the beginning and at the end of a string, but  it does not made the trick. Try yourself, json parse online tools say that json is corrupted.

Comment: Suppose you need to substring() the json string and get the part with json { }

Comment: Put data in quotes `"data"`. Missing quotes is a syntax error in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the json string the JSON string should look like this

```
{
    "data":
    { 
        "type": "add",
        "newsId": "5da979e0-161d-11e7-9e14-bd201bbe920c",
        "articleId": "null",
        "category": "news",
        "timestamp": "1490970103941",
        "id": "5daa8b50-161d-11e7-9e14-bd201bbe920c"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this way:

```
myObj = {
    "type": "add",
    "newsId": "5da979e0-161d-11e7-9e14-bd201bbe920c",
     "articleId": "null",
     "category": "news",
     "timestamp": "1490970103941",
     "id": "5daa8b50-161d-11e7-9e14-bd201bbe920c"
 }
var type = myObj.type;
var newsId= myObj.newsId;
var articleId=myObj.articleId;
var category= myObj.category;
var timestamp= myObj.timestamp;
var id=myObj.id;
```

Hope it will help you